# Storing sensitive infomation

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, encryption

One of my java class will connect to a another server and do some operation using rest services. Java class requires - username and password to connect to remote server. On other machines we used to store the credentials using oracle cwallet.sso but this is not an option for current machine. I am thinking to store the encrypted password in properties file adding some salt. I also need to store the key and salt string to some secure place. do we have any alternative in RHEL for password management like cwallet or any suggestions what to should be the best way to achieve this?

Please note that I will invoke this class using shell script.

Thanks

Comment: Wich SO are you going to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky, because if someone gets access to your server is already game over. So the solution is not just to encrypt the data, as it won't do much, but you need security in depth.

To put this in context, you can have the password encrypted, salted whatever... When an attacker gets access to the server, he won't be able to read any of those files (even with the encrypted password) unless he is able to become the user running the app. If he manages to do that, he only needs to do a memory dump and then fish for passwords (which is not hard).

So a real world solution is:

- Only allow a restricted number of people to log on the server.
- Only allow an even smaller number to become the user which runs the application server.

  - This group of people are the ones who can read/update the properties file
- Disable any kind of backups on the files that contain secrets.

Again, encrypting passwords on the files might give you a sense of security, but again, if you follow the steps above, anyone who can read the file, will also be able to read the memory contents of the app. And even if someone does things right and stores that password in an bit of offheap memory, some linux tools can read the whole memory map of a process, so again, game over.

Using encryption in this case just adds obscurity and no real protection.

Comment: I agree nothing is secure. Infra/security team will make sure of limited access. As a programmer I am looking some suggestions on the best possible ways we can achieve the security.

Comment: Use 2-factor authentication on the server. Carefully control who has the second factor, it is to easy to forget to remove authorization. Use company issued phones if the 2nd factor is an SMS or email. A hard token is best, you can track the serial numbers against users. You can loan a token and get it back, you can't loan a password.